# Clicking on image 'pushes' the rest of the list underneath image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to build a simple list component that displays images when a title is clicked. For each title you can open the corresponding image(s), that al works fine, but the problem is that the rest of the titles (the list) is pushed underneath the image(s).

The desired result should be that the images are displayed to the right of the list without affecting the list.

I've tried separating the component into two components, so where the image is called in the ternary operator putting a component like `<ProjectImage src={project.src} alt={project.altText}/>` but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

```
import {items} from '../ProjectInfo/projectObjects'


export class Sidenav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: false, items: items};
    this.showProjectOnClick = this.showProjectOnClick.bind(this);
  }

showProjectOnClick(event){
const checkActive = this.state.items.id === items.id
const activeProject = {...event, active: !checkActive}
  this.setState(state => ({
    isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn,
    activeProject
  }));
}

  render() {
    const {items} = this.state
    return (
          <div className="sidenav">
         {items.map((project) => {
           return ( <div className="Box" key={project.id}>
              <p className={this.state.isToggleOn && this.state.activeProject.id === project.id ? 'P_Color' : null}
                 onClick={() => {this.showProjectOnClick(project)}}><b>Project name: </b>{project.title}</p>
                {
                this.state.isToggleOn && this.state.activeProject.id === project.id 
                ? 
              <div className="ProjectImageBox">
                <img className="ProjectImage" src={project.src} alt={project.altText}/> 
              </div>
                : ''
                }
            </div>)
            })}
         </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image: The Project List Component while closed]
**The project list**
[image: The Project List Component currently while open]
**The current result when a title is clicked**
[image: The Project List Component the way I would like it to be]
**The desired result**

Comment: What's the desired behavior?

Comment: I've edited my question to make that more clear.

Comment: You are rendering an array of items with each a seperate imagebox. You could use css to make the position of the box absolute and render this one. What I would suggest is creating a different component and keeping the selecteditem in your state and passing this to your image component, rendering the correct image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with css.

```
.image{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 40px;
}
```

**But a better option** would be using a different component and passing the selected item to this component. This reduces the amount of components and you just have to position them accordingly. I have created a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lub71g) showing how this works.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to absolute position you image so it doesn't take up the space in the list.

the css class should be the following:

```css
.image {
  position: "absolute";
  top: 0;
  left: "100%";
  /* the propreties below you can customize */
  width: "50px";
  height: "auto";
}
```